# Specify world file to use in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing

I have a BMP file where I know the coords of the corners, and hence have a generated a World File according to ESRI's standards. It has the the right filename, but when I add the image in ArcMap, it complains there's no spatial information.

Things I've tried:

- Turned on the "Use world file to define the coordinates of a raster" option
- Different extensions for the world file - BMPW, BMW, BPW
- Trying the help... the directions it gives are for a *link* file, which has to be imported manually for each raster (I'll have hundreds to these rasters)

So the question is: how do I get ArcGIS to use the world file?

Comment: World file—extension *.bpw http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Supported_raster_dataset_file_formats needs to be formatted correctly http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=3121&pid=3109&topicname=World%20files%20for%20raster%20datasets&

Comment: Would recommend png or tif rather than bitmap from experience (mainly due to file size and resolution)

Comment: Did you give it a projection definition as well?  The world file won't contain that.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your world file. In my experience ESRI software is *very* picky about formatting, right down to being sensitive to the placement of whitespace. (The most reliable way to create a world file that will be correctly read is to start with an existing, working one--ask the software to create it if you need to--and modify it *very carefully*.)  BTW, a "link file" is for "warping," not for establishing the affine transformation connecting (row, col) coordinates to world coordinates. It sounds like you may be reading an irrelevant help page.

Comment: There are two possible issues: 1) ignoring the warning message, does the image overlay with other data when the data frame is set to the bmp's coordinate system? If so, the world file is working correctly. 2) As johns says, you still have to define the coordinate system of the image. Once that's done, ArcGIS will be able to project it to other coordinate systems.

Comment: Re: World files - yes, ARCGIs is *very* picky. The number of decimal places matter. (Create a random world file and then edit in notepad or similar.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the message you see is something like "you are missing a Spatial Reference", then the world file is alright. The world file cannot define the SR (spatial reference). To do this, right-click your image in Catalog, select Properties, scroll down to the Spatial Reference section, click "Edit" to define the Spatial Reference. This will generate a *.aux.xml file (for BMP) containing the SR information. Now, as you add the BMP image to ArcMap, you will not see the "missing SR" message.